# Angular Material Select - preselecting multiple values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my case angular role is to receive *JSON-entity* from *API* and assign it's values to `FormGroup`.
Everything works fine (`FormGroup` contains all expected values), but `mat-select` does not visually preselect given values.

All functionality described before is contained in `onInit()` method.

***product-group-update.component.ts:***
*full code: https://pastebin.com/hXLqBAcF*

```
export class ProductGroupUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  NO_PRODUCT: string = 'No product';
  editProductGroupForm: FormGroup;
  id: number;
  isFormSubmitted = false;
  availableProducts: Product[];
  toSelect: Product[];
 
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private productGroupService: ProductGroupService,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
 
  ) {
  }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editProductGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      products: ['', []],
    });
 
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params.get('id');
      this.productGroupService.getProductGroupById(this.id).subscribe(
        receivedProductGroup => {
          this.toSelect = receivedProductGroup.products;
          this.editProductGroupForm.setValue({
            name: receivedProductGroup.name,
            description: receivedProductGroup.description,
            products: receivedProductGroup.products,
          });
        }
      );
    });
    console.log(this.editProductGroupForm)
 
    this.productService.getAllProducts(new Page<Product>()).subscribe(response => {
      this.availableProducts = response.content;
    });
  }
 
  ...

}
```

***product-group-update-component.html***
*full code: https://pastebin.com/9GqyU2r2*

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="card card-container">
 
    <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" [formGroup]="editProductGroupForm" class="new-obj-form" id="register-form">
      

      ...

 
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Products</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="products" multiple [(value)]="toSelect">
          <mat-option [value]="NO_PRODUCT">{{NO_PRODUCT}}</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let product of availableProducts" [value]="product">
            {{product.name}}
            <i><small>(ID: {{product.id}})</small></i>
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
 

    ...
 

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**As you can see: `editProductGroupForm` contains all the values:**
[image: editProductGroupForm in console]

**And `toSelect` element (from which mat-select should take preselected values) too:**
[image: toSelect in console]

**But mat-select does not preselect any values:**
[image: mat-select]

Other code:

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  groupId: number;
  sold: boolean;
}


import {Product} from "./product";

export interface ProductGroup {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  products: Product[];
}
```

Comment: In Angular, when using the subscribe you cannot ensure that the data arrives before the page is rendered, to check if this is the problem you could establish a resolver so that the rendering of the component waits for the data, or to try to include the mat-select a * ngIf = "this.toSelect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in mind, that the Products in `availableProducts` and `toSelect` are different objects. So, when even though they have all the same properties, they are still different instances, meaning the comparison of the objects will return a false - that's why they're not selected.

You can fix it using two different approaches:

1. `mat-select` supports the `compareWith` function - so you can override the default comparison and compare them, say, by Id. See official angular docs [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection) for how it works. An example is avaialable in [material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#getting-and-setting-the-select-value) as well.
2. Use rxjs to combine both of your API calls and make sure that your `toSelect` are actual instances of the objects from the `availableProducts` table.